# Can a creature with Freedom of Movement on it spend its movement to get out of a grapple when it isn't its turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, grapple

[Freedom of Movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/freedom-of-movement) doesn't prevent grapples or the Grappled condition.  You can spend 5 movement to end the grapple.  Can you "spend" this movement to get out of the grapple immediately (i.e. on the grappling opponent's turn)?

Setup: A Kraken has a multiattack allowing it to make 3 tentacle attacks or to substitute its Fling ability for any tentacle attack.  When a tentacle attack hits, the creature being attacked is automatically Grappled.  A Fling action allows a held or Grappled creature to be thrown 60 ft, causing damage and a Prone condition.

Scenario: A Kraken can use its Multi-attack to attack a creature with Freedom of Movement on it, cause the Grappled condition, then with it's next action Fling the Grappled creature.

Can the creature with FoM prevent this Fling during the Kraken's turn by spending 5 of its next turn's (or last turn's "saved") movement to escape the grapple?

RAW it seems that the Kraken would be able to do anything it wanted to a FoM enhanced individual as it would any other.  In fact, if using Legendary Actions it could Grapple after the FoM character's turn and then on its own turn Bite (and thus Swallow Whole) the FoM character.  Does this seem to be the intention?  Or should the Kraken not be able to grab and eat the FoM character (assuming they have movement to spend)?

Edit: Removed my talk about saving movement or not being able to spend movement you don't have.  Per SageAdvice (https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/12/15/is-freedom-of-movement-broken/) you can spend movement when your movement is 0.  So the issue isn't if you can spend movement (that you may not have) but if you can do it on an opponents turn (to prevent further bad effects that can result from being Grappled).

Comment: @NautArch you are right, I misread the first paragraph.

Answer (score 8):

### You cannot prevent the Kraken's attack through the Freedom of Movement spell.

The general rule is that you have a certain amount of movement that you may use on your turn.  You may not save this movement or use it before your turn, except in the case of a readied action.

> **Movement and Position** (*PHB p 190*)
>
> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as
>   much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn....

If you spend your Action on your turn, and specify a specific trigger that would let you move with your remaining movement for the current turn, you may later spend your reaction to move if/when the trigger occurs.

> **Ready** *(PHB p 193)*
>
> First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, or you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

Their may be specific class abilities or items that allow exceptions to this rule, but in that case you should refer to their text.

XGtE defines the Scout Archetype for the Rogue class.  You can gain this ability:

> **Skirmisher** *(XGtE p47)*
>
> Starting at 3rd level , you are difficult to pin down during a fight. You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of you. This movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks.

However, this ability grants you the ability to move, which is probably not the same thing as granting you movement that you can use to stand up or for other abilities such as Freedom of Movement.

The only way that I can see you preventing this from happening would be if you readied an escape attempt with the trigger of being grappled by the Kraken.  This would use up your entire Action, your Reaction if it occurs and you decide to react, and then you still have the chance of failing your ability check to escape.

Maybe a Fire Shield would keep you from being so tasty since it would burn the Kraken whenever it makes a melee attack.  Many DMs would consider maintaining a grapple and/or swallowing a creature to be close enough to trigger such melee effects 1/round.  Since it doesn't rely on concentration, you might even kill the Kraken with your fiery corpse burning it inside out.

Comment: Skirmisher ability is an interesting possibility. I asked specifically about that [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114230/can-you-use-freedom-of-movement-with-the-rogue-skirmisher-reaction).

Comment: I updated my question with an edit noted above.  It seems that you can spend movement you don't have to escape a grapple.  The crux of the question then becomes can you do this when it isn't your turn?

Comment: Still not sure that you would be allowed to take any kind of (re)action in order to even do this.  Even with the Skirmisher ability, it only kicks in *at the end* of the enemy's turn.  Freedom of Movement does not grant you an option for a Reaction, so I don't think you could escape on the Kraken's turn anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## You need a Reaction to act out of your turn

Unfortunately, the only way to do something out of your turn is through a Reaction.

As an example, a reaction could be set up through the [Ready Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready). However, taking the Ready Action would use up your Action on your turn (so no moving or attacking.)

Otherwise, you can not move or act on someone else's turn.