# If my Scout rogue has used his full movement on his turn, can he later use the reaction from the Skirmisher feature to move again?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, rogue, reactions

Here is the situation I am wondering about:

My Rogue is in melee with an opponent.  On his turn he disengages, and moves his full movement away from his opponent.  The opponent, on their turn, uses their full movement to put themselves within 5 feet of my Rogue again, ending their turn.  Can my Rogue then use the Skirmisher ability and move an additional 1/2 speed, or is the reaction essentially wasted because my Rogue has already used his full movement this turn?

I am leaning towards no.

Comment: Could you please clarify and/or rephrase the question? The '53' is confusing. It seems you are asking if a particular rogue ability allows you to move using your reaction, even if you have already moved your maximum speed. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. @Token: I'm guessing the "53" is actually meant to be "5e", given that the two keys are next to one another (and "53" has no other obvious meaning in this context). Greg, can you confirm whether this is the case?

Comment: Related: [Can you use Freedom of Movement with the Rogue Skirmisher Reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114230/can-you-use-freedom-of-movement-with-the-rogue-skirmisher-reaction), [Can you stand up from being prone using Skirmisher outside of your turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146783/can-you-stand-up-from-being-prone-using-skirmisher-outside-of-your-turn)

Answer (score 19):

## Yes, he can.

The [Scout rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Scout)'s [Skirmisher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Skirmisher-740) feature says:

> You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of you. This movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks.

Note that this ability uses your reaction, not your "movement". You don't have a pool of [movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition) outside your turn, normally:

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here.

There are no general rules for willingly moving (as opposed to being forcefully moved by someone or something else) outside your turn. You normally have a pool of movement on your turn equal to your speed, and none outside it.

The Scout rogue's Skirmisher feature gives them a special way to move outside their turn. It lets them use their reaction when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of them, and specifies that the Scout can move a distance up to half its speed. This doesn't depend at all on how much (or how little) you moved on your turn. You can use this reaction if the requirement is met, regardless of whether you moved on your own turn.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes. You can use that reaction even if you had moved your entire speed on your turn.

The accepted answer to this linked question, [Can you use Freedom of Movement with the Rogue Skirmisher Reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114244/49864) in V2Blast's comment may have exactly the answer you are looking for.

As stated there, your movement on your turn allows you to move up to your speed. Any other ability like the scout's skirmisher or even the battlemaster's maneuvering strike that allow characters to move with their reaction use rules independent of those that let you move your speed on your turn.