# Does Cunning Action: Aim affect a Scout Rogue's skirmisher ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, rogue, unearthed-arcana

I wanted to make sure my assumptions were correct that the Cunning Action: Aim would not affect a Scout Rogue's Skirmisher ability.

As I understand, according to the Class Feature Variants UA

> You can use this bonus action only if you haven't moved during this turn, and after you use the bonus action, your speed is 0 until the end of the current turn.

and the Scouts class feature Skirmisher (Xanathar's Guide to Everything)

> Starting at 3rd level, you are difficult to pin down during a fight. You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of you. This movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks.

Because Skirmisher happens as a reaction at the end of an enemy's turn the Rogue's movement would no longer be 0 due to the Cunning Action: Aim. Is the assumption correct?

Comment: Have you also checked out the Rogue/Scout in Xanathar's Guide to Everything?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I _believe_ the reference to UA is just for the Class Feature Variants, and they probably are using the XGtE version of the Scout rogue; that said, this is just my assumption, and it might be good for OP to clarify either way. (This is on top of the assumption that you believe they might be using the old UA Scout rogue; is that what your comment meant?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Correct, the skirmisher can potentially move again once its no longer their turn

The relevant point is that your turn starts and ends at your point in the initiative order.

To re-iterate the parts you already quoted in the question - but with some words in bold:

> You can use this bonus action only if you haven't moved during **this
> turn**, and after you use the bonus action, your speed is 0 until the
> end of the **current turn**.

> You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy ends
> **its turn** within 5 feet of you.

Once it's an enemy's turn, it is no longer your turn, so the movement restriction no longer applies. In fact, it doesn't matter whether you moved or not during your turn. The skirmisher ability says you may move up to half your speed as a reaction during the enemy turn, so this is what you may do regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Cunning Action Aim says:

> You can use this **bonus action** only if you haven't moved during this turn, and after you use the bonus action, your speed is 0 until the **end of the current turn**.

You can only use a bonus action on your own turn, the scope of the effect ends when your turn ends.

Skirmisher reads:

> You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy **ends its turn** within 5 feet of you.

This ability triggers when it is *not your turn*, so it does not interact with Cunning Action: Aim, and it [*does not expend your available movement on your next turn*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150381/62294).